# Java/Spring-Boot Webapp not Serving Assets from Public Resources Directory

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on an AngularJS application that's being served by Spring-Boot. I'm in the process of upgrading our build pipeline to include Webpack. Webpack is bundling all of the source code into a `/src/main/resources/static` directory, which I'm told SHOULD be served automatically by Spring-Boot. However, when I try to test this out by navigating to `http://localhost:8080`, the `index.html` page is being served, but the various JS bundles are not. Below are some of the relevant files to configure this:

webpack.config.js

```
/*global process, module, __dirname*/

const path = require('path');
const proxyMiddleware = require('proxy-middleware');
const url = require('url');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, './src/main/webapp'),
    dist: path.join(__dirname, './src/main/resources/static'),
    test: path.join(__dirname, './src/test/webapp')
};

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'develop';
const isE2E = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'e2e';
const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// Webpack Loaders
const fontRule = {
    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[name].[sha1:hash:base64:32].[ext]'
    }
};

const htmlRule = {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader',
    query: {
        minimize: isProd
    }
};

const imageRule = {
    test: /\.png$/i,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        limit: 8192,
        mimetype: 'image/png'
    }
};

const javasscriptPreRule = {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    enforce: 'pre',
    loader: 'eslint-loader'
};

const javascriptRule = {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
};

const sassRule = {
    test : /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [ 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap' ]
    })
};

const entry = {
    app: (() => {
        let app = [ path.join(PATHS.app, 'app.js') ];

        if (isProd || isE2E) {
            app.push(path.join(PATHS.app, 'app.prod.js'));
        } else {
            app.push(path.join(PATHS.app, 'app.mock.js'));
        }

        return app;
    })()
};

const output = {
    path: PATHS.dist,
    filename: isProd ? '[name].[chunkhash].js' : '[name].js'
};

const plugins = (() => {
    let plugins = [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks(module) {
                return module.context
                    && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
            }
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'manifest' }),

        new ExtractTextPlugin(isProd ? 'styles.[contenthash].css' : 'styles.css'),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(PATHS.app, 'index.html') }),

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        })
    ];

    if (isProd) {
        plugins = plugins.concat([
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                beautify: false,
                comments: false,
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                }
            }),

            new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),

            new OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin({
                cssProcessorOptions: {
                    discardComments: { removeAll: true }
                }
            })
        ]);
    } else {
        const server = (() => {
            let server = {
                baseDir: PATHS.dist
            };

            // Internal testing server configurations...

            return server;
        })();

        plugins.push(
            new BrowserSyncPlugin({
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                server
            })
        )
    }

    return plugins;
})();

function proxy(target) {
    let options = url.parse(target);
    options.route = '/api';

    return proxyMiddleware(options);
}

module.exports = {
    entry,
    output,
    plugins,
    module: {
        rules: [ fontRule, htmlRule, imageRule, javasscriptPreRule, javascriptRule, sassRule ]
    }
};
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements InitializingBean {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                // Internal security configurations
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

Here are the static files stored in `/src/target/classes/static`:

[image: Built files]

And here is proof that the JS files aren't showing up when opening the browser:

[image: Firefox Output]

Comment: Post the directory output of `target/classes/static`. That's a giant Webpack config dump, but it doesn't clearly show that files are being saved in the right place (or at the right time, which in Maven would be the `generate-resources` phase).

Comment: I've updated my original post with a screenshot of `target/classes/static`.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like those are there. What about your Network tab--are you getting 404s? Something else?

Comment: Only the HTML file is being fetched, no other resources unfortunately.

Comment: That's not an answer. It doesn't say whether the other resources aren't being *requested* (you didn't include a `script` tag), or whether there's some other problem (with the exact error message).

Comment: My apologies. I think I know what the error is, though I still don't know the solution to the problem. The front-end code for this project is hosted in the `src/main/webapp` directory, which appears to be where Spring-Boot will serve files by default. The `index.html` file doesn't have the built `vendor`, `manifest`, or `app` JS files linked by default (they're included by Webpack during the build process). I need to configure Spring-Boot to serve the front-end code from `target/classes/static`, rather than `src/main/webapp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem that I was running into. Spring-Boot was still defaulting to `src/main/webapp` to serve the front-end code. While there is an `index.html` file within that directory, it doesn't contain `<script>` tags for the JavaScript bundles generated by Webpack; Webpack takes care of automatically adding those tags. I had to change the directory where the bundle files were being loaded from.

To do this, I edited the `src/main/resources/application.properties` file, and added the following line:

`spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/`